# Efficient filtering of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, calculation

I have the following dataframe:

```
item         = ['item1','item2','item3']
amount       = [500,200,800]
feature_2020 = [18,32,34]
feature_2030 = [28,42,44]
feature_2040 = [38,52,54]
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':item,'amount':amount,'feature_2020': feature_2020,'feature_2030':feature_2030,'feature_2040':feature_2040})
df.index= df['index']
print(df)



         amount   feature_2020  feature_2030  feature_2040  index
index                                                         
item1     500            18            28            38     item1
item2     200            32            42            52     item2
item3     800            34            44            54     item3
```

I want to efficiently do the following (I can already do it but in a really bad way):

- For each feature column (feature_2020,feature_2030,feature_2040), I want to filter values strictly under 20, between 20 included and strictly under 40, and above 40 included.
- Once this filter applied, I want to compute the sum of the amount column of remaining items for each category filtered above.

Expected result:

```
inf20            = [500,1000,0]
supequal20_inf40 = [0,500,1000]
supequal40       = [0,500,1000]
index            = ['inf20','supequal20_inf40','supequal40']
result = pd.DataFrame({'sum_feature_2020':inf20,'sum_feature_2030':supequal20_inf40,'sum_feature_2040': supequal40,'index':index})
result.index= result['index']
print(result)



              sum_feature_2020  sum_feature_2030    sum_feature_2040                                                     
inf20               500                0                  0
supequal20_inf40    1000               500                500
supequal40           0                 1000               1000
```

Is there a way to do this filtering and operation in an efficient way?

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: The values in feature_2030  and feature_2040 belong to the same categories. Why do the results differ?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in the result section, i had the matrix inverted. I have updated the post with good results. @RafaelC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'd melt it, to put all the values we want to bin in one column, then I'd bin it using `pd.cut`, and then I'd pivot back.

```
d2 = df.melt(["index", "amount"])
d2["binned"] = pd.cut(d2.value, [0, 20, 40, np.inf], right=False)
out = d2.pivot_table(index="binned", columns="variable",
                     values="amount", aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)
```

which gives me

```
In [172]: out
Out[172]: 
variable      feature_2020  feature_2030  feature_2040
binned                                                
[0.0, 20.0)          500.0           0.0           0.0
[20.0, 40.0)        1000.0         500.0         500.0
[40.0, inf)            0.0        1000.0        1000.0
```

by way of

```
In [173]: d2
Out[173]: 
   index  amount      variable  value        binned
0  item1     500  feature_2020     18   [0.0, 20.0)
1  item2     200  feature_2020     32  [20.0, 40.0)
2  item3     800  feature_2020     34  [20.0, 40.0)
3  item1     500  feature_2030     28  [20.0, 40.0)
4  item2     200  feature_2030     42   [40.0, inf)
5  item3     800  feature_2030     44   [40.0, inf)
6  item1     500  feature_2040     38  [20.0, 40.0)
7  item2     200  feature_2040     52   [40.0, inf)
8  item3     800  feature_2040     54   [40.0, inf)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, less generalized way

```
x = df.set_index('amount')[[ 'feature_2020', 'feature_2030', 'feature_2040']]

r1 = x.lt(20).mul(x.index, axis=0).sum()
r2 = (x.ge(20) & x.lt(40)).mul(x.index, axis=0).sum()
r3 = x.ge(40).mul(x.index, axis=0).sum()

df_f = pd.concat([r1,r2,r3], 1).T

    feature_2020    feature_2030    feature_2040
0   500             0               0
1   1000            500             500
2   0               1000            1000
```